# Springboot @postmapping not working on gcloud but functional on localhost

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with the following `@postMapping` annotation and I am able to POST to the application on localhost.
However I get an error when I use the public URL for the service on gcloud.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-07-21T13:25:02.618+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/"
}
```

Using postman I have tested POST action on localhost and it is working fine.
Here is the annotation on the controller method:

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "/api/receivepayload",
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
```

However when I test after deploying on the gcloud server (with postman again), I get `Request method 'POST' is not supported` as in the following log:

> ```
> 2023-07-21T13:24:45.257Z  INFO 287041 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2023-07-21T13:24:45.258Z  INFO 287041 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2023-07-21T13:24:45.260Z  INFO 287041 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
> 2023-07-21T13:25:02.616Z  WARN 287041 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]
> ```

Comment: can you add `@CrossOrigin` and retry ?

Comment: Issue was the server address I was using for post. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because of the end point I was using in post man. Although I had configured the application to receive REST call using the http://gcloudserverip:8080/api/receivepayload, I was posting to http://gcloudserver:8080 hence the error.

Apologies.